# What is the best way to keep a MySQL table replicated across multiple web sites?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, synchronization

I have multiple sites running the same custom CMS software. While the content needs to be different, it would be nice to have a shared member database (just for the convenience of a single sign on). In this case it got me wondering what the best way would be to have 5 databases share their user logon tables and stay fairly synced up.

Has anyone ran into and solved this problem before?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they hosted on the same server?  If so, why not have each site use a single `members` database?

Comment: I've never done this myself but I did consider a thought model.  Wherever your sites are, have a single user database table.  Write a simple GET API to allow remote authentication a la facebook (and stack exchange!) For greater robustness, you could have the db table self-replicate across other sites.  (Every time a user record is updated, call a single page which then pushes the data to all your sites)  If you need more detail, comment and I'll post the thought model in the answer.